# What is wrong in this sentence . Its vs their

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> An elephant relies on its trunk for their highly developed sense of smell.

Comment: An elephant/its/their.  Make them agree!

Answer (score 1):

> An elephant relies on its trunk for its highly developed sense of
> smell.
>
> Elephants rely on their trunks for their highly developed sense of
> smell.

You have to make the numbers agree.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Hot Licks' answer, I suspect you are stumbling over the contradictory concepts of "Don't call animals 'it'", "Don't call people 'them'", and "Don't call people by the wrong pronouns".

These are contradictory, and should really just be guidelines (not hard rules) except for the last one -- ONCE you know it.

Calling an elephant 'it' or 'them' is fine.